# VBA "Compile Eror: Invalid or unqualified reference" Application.FileDialog

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to run this VBA macro is says "Compile error: invalid or unqualified reference". Here is the relevant portion of the macro:

The first .Filters.Add with "Excel 2003" is highlighted as the offending part.

I even tried "On Error Resume Next: and it didn't help bypass the error, which surprised me.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DataProcessingExperiment7()

'   Reduces CPU intensity + macro execution time since data types can be managed
Application.CalculationxlCalculationManual

On Error Resume Next
'  Declare as strings, as integers, as variants, decDecimals, as Office.FileDialog
Dim strPath, strFileN, strDirN, strCPath, strRangeNOut, strRangeNIn, strTLCorn, strBRCorn, strtemp_name As String
Dim iStartcol, iStartrow, iColNo, iStep, iPlateNo, iRowIn As Integer
Dim vResMatrix() As Variant
Dim decBgrSum, decBgrVal, decVolcorr
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
'   MEeff = measure of efflux due to crudely purified HDL in scintillation
'   Math operations are fastest with Integers / UIntegers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae55hdtk.aspx

'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
    **.Filters**.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2003 Macro-Enabled", "*.xlsm"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*."
With fd
    If .Show = -1 Then
        txtFileName = vrtSelectedItem
        MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
    End If
'   Excel 2003 is a good filter choice: Excel Viewer, OpenOffice, + Excel versions can open these files
'   If .Show = - 1 user picked at least one file
    Next vrtSelectedItem
    Else
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `On Error Resume Next` would not avoid compile errors because compilation happens before the code even starts running :) `On Error Resume Next` only helps once the code is running.

Your error is occurring because you do have unqualified references, all three `.Filters.Add` lines. I see what you are trying to do, and to fix it you need to put them inside the `With fd` statement. See the below link for a further example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx

> ```
> Sub UseFileDialogOpen() 
>
>     Dim lngCount As Long 
>
>     ' Open the file dialog 
>     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) 
>         .AllowMultiSelect = True 
>         .Show 
>
>         ' Display paths of each file selected 
>         For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count 
>             MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount) 
>         Next lngCount 
>
>     End With
>
> End Sub
> ```